# CSS3 animations work on click

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm attempting to make a welcome page that, once you click on it, will fall by a CSS transition.
I can't figure out how to make the page fall, I can only make the button fall when the page loads.

here's what I have:

```
<style>
pt-page-rotateFall {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-animation: rotateFall 1s both ease-in;
     animation: rotateFall 1s both ease-in;} 
a {
    color:black;
      text-align:center;
      -moz-transition:all 1s ease; -webkit-transition:all 1s ease;        transition:all 1s ease;
    -o-transition:all 1s ease; -ms-transition:all 1s ease;
}
a:focus {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
20% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(10deg); -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
40% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(17deg); }
60% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(16deg); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%) rotateZ(17deg); }

0% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg); transform: rotateZ(0deg); }
20% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(10deg); transform: rotateZ(10deg); -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
40% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(17deg); transform: rotateZ(17deg); }
60% { -webkit-transform: rotateZ(16deg); transform: rotateZ(16deg); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%) rotateZ(17deg); transform: translateY(100%) rotateZ(17deg); }
```

}

Welcome

Answer (score 0):

You will need Javascript to do that. You could either handle the animation itself in Javascript completely, or add a click event listener and give the element the class pt-pate-rotateFall within the handler.